# How to use a DatePicker control in Asp.Net using jQuery

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to popup a calendar control when a textbox is focused. Everything is working except the calendar control is not showing up.

The code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#txt_date').datepicker();
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_date" Class="txt_date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is not jQueryUI... You need jQueryUI too :)

Answer (score 0):

you also need to include [JqueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script> <--This is path to jqueryUI
  $( function() {
    $( "#txt_date" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
 </head>
<body>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_date" Class="txt_date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```